# How do i find the peak number of vehicles and peak times

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table containing records relating to public transportation. I need to know what time of day the peak vehicles were out and how many vehicles.
The date range would be a fiscal year, from 7/1/yyyy to 6/30/yyyy.
My table is called fixedrouterecords and here is a sample of the relevant columns.

I have tried using some of the examples for peak users, but could not get there.

```
service_date    bus leave_yard  return_to_yard
 2016-10-24     104  05:15:00    06:30:00
 2016-10-24     204  04:10:00    06:30:00
```

of course there are thousands of lines for a fiscal year

Comment: Do you need to know this for each day, or are you looking for an average/estimated peak hour-of-day over some period like a week/month/year?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, it's a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: Database (Oracle 11gR2 / MySQL 5.7 / SQL Server 2008 etc ...)?

Comment: How specific does the peak window need to be? Do you need to know the hour, min etc?

Comment: I need to know the average number of vehicles used at the peak times over a fiscal year. And I need to know what these average peak times were.I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and need to know the hour

Comment: Do they always leave the yard at say 5 min intervals and return at times like 6:30? or could it be like 4:31 to 6:31

Comment: What is your definition of peak?

Comment: @RBarryYoung The downvote might be because the question lacks research effort, is unclear, or not useful. It's not my downvote, but I think a fair case could be made for at least two of those reasons - which is perhaps why 42 mins later, the OP is no nearer an answer.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Have a look at this similar problem: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/calculating-concurrent-sessions-part-3

Comment: @dnoeth Also, have a look at the names of the three people who solved it... ;-)

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I know, I've seen it before. Have a look at names in the 2003 version: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/calculating-concurrent-sessions  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generate Peak Times by service day

```
Declare @YourTable table (service_date date,bus int,leave_yard Time,return_to_yard time)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2016-10-24',104,'05:15:00','06:30:00'),
('2016-10-24',204,'04:10:00','06:30:00'),
('2016-10-25',997,'05:15:00','06:30:00'),
('2016-10-25',998,'04:10:00','06:30:00'),
('2016-10-25',999,'05:30:00','06:00:00'),
('2016-10-26',999,'06:30:00','07:15:00')

;with cte0(N) as (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N))
    , cteT(T) as (Select Top 1440 cast(DateAdd(MI,Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))-1,'1900-01-01') as time) From cte0 N1, cte0 N2, cte0 N3, cte0 N4) 
    , cteBase as (
         Select service_date
               ,bus
               ,OutTime = T
         From   @YourTable A
         Join   cteT B
         on     T between leave_yard and return_to_yard
         Where  Year(service_date)=2016  -- or any other filter you like  
      )
Select A.Service_Date
      ,A.MinOut 
      ,A.MaxOut 
      ,Busses = count(Distinct B.Bus)
 From (
        Select Service_Date
              ,MinOut = Min(A.OutTime)
              ,MaxOut = Max(A.OutTime)
         From (
                Select *,Rnk=Rank() over (Partition By Service_Date Order by Hits Desc)
                 From (Select Service_Date,OutTime,Hits=count(*) From cteBase Group by Service_Date,OutTime ) A
               ) A 
         Where Rnk=1
         Group By Service_Date
      ) A
 Join cteBase B on A.Service_Date=B.Service_Date and B.OutTime between A.MinOut and A.MaxOut
 Group By A.Service_Date,A.MinOut,A.MaxOut
```

**This shows PEAK Usage by Service Day**

```
Service_Date    MinOut   MaxOut    Busses
2016-10-24     05:15:00  06:30:00  2
2016-10-25     05:30:00  06:00:00  3
2016-10-26     06:30:00  07:15:00  1
```

Comment: Even more perfect. This provides the number of peak vehicles per day and the peak times for that day. Even more then I expected this morning

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way but I think it should work. Assuming you have a 24 hour window for this (based on limited info) I would use a view or a CTE and create a column for duration and for each hour of the day (ie 01,02,03 etc)

Then I would use the leave_yard + Duration to determine for what hours in the day the bus was out (ie the formula to populate the value for 01 is)

```
 Case WHEN leave_yard > 01:00 AND leave_yard < (leave_yard + duration) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS '01'
```

So you set each hour column for that day as 1 or 0 then sum the hours so you get the number of buses out in each hour each day. Then compare the hours either with another expression and roll up with aggregates etc

Answer (score 0):

```
select      service_date
           ,vehicles_out
           ,ts              as from_time
           ,next_ts         as to_time

from       (select      t.*
                       ,rank () over (partition by service_date order by vehicles_out desc) as rnk

            from       (select      service_date
                                   ,ts
                                   ,sum  (op) over (partition by service_date order by ts,op,bus)   as vehicles_out
                                   ,lead (ts) over (partition by service_date order by ts,op,bus)   as next_ts

                        from        (           select service_date ,bus ,leave_yard     as ts , 1 as op from fixedrouterecords 
                                    union all   select service_date ,bus ,return_to_yard       ,-1       from fixedrouterecords 
                                    ) t
                        ) t
            ) t

where       rnk = 1
;
```

Comment: this is the error I get Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: @BobbyKuhn, fixed, then GROUP BY was a garbage from another verison

Comment: it does not recognize Lead. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 I am getting the same errors but lead is underlined and says it is not a recognized built in function name

Comment: @BobbyKuhn, Yep... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234.aspx It is posibble to remove the analytics functions and use more basic code but it is going to be ugly as hell and and perform lousy. I draw the line here :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT phour AS peak_hour,
       bus_cnt AS peak_count
  FROM
     (
       SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY bus_cnt DESC ) AS rnk       
         FROM 
            (
               SELECT cast( DATEPART( hour, leave_yard ) as varchar )+ ':00:00' AS phour,
                      COUNT( bus ) AS bus_cnt 
                 FROM fixedrouterecords
                GROUP BY phour
             ) A
    ) B
```

WHERE rnk = 1
    ;

Comment: I get an error message saying Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT - Removed the need for the UDF and added an ad-hoc tally**

```
Declare @YourTable table (service_date date,bus int,leave_yard Time,return_to_yard time)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2016-10-24',104,'05:15:00','06:30:00'),
('2016-10-24',204,'04:10:00','06:30:00')

;with cte0(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N))
    , cteT(T) As (Select Top 1440 cast(DateAdd(MI,Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))-1,'1900-01-01') as time) From cte0 N1, cte0 N2, cte0 N3, cte0 N4) 
    , cteBase as (
         Select service_date
               ,bus
               ,OutTime = T
         From   @YourTable A             -- << Replace with Your Table Name
         Join   cteT B
         on     T between leave_yard and return_to_yard
         Where  Year(service_date)=2016  -- << Or any other filter you like  
      )
Select MinOut 
      ,MaxOut
      ,Busses = count(Distinct bus)
 From (
        Select Top 1 
               Hits
              ,MinOut=min(OutTime)
              ,MaxOut=max(OutTime)
         From  (Select OutTime,Hits=count(*) from cteBase group by OutTime) A
         Group By Hits
         Order By Hits Desc
       ) A
 Join cteBase B on (OutTime between MinOut and MaxOut)
 Group By MinOut,MaxOut
```

Returns

```
MinOut      MaxOut      Busses
05:15:00    06:30:00    2
```

Comment: that works perfectly. I tested the results, without alias, on the live database and then applied logic to the return of a single day and this does exactly what we are looking for.

Comment: I add to add a group by service_date to run the year, otherwise it brings back all the distinct vehicles that ran that year. I need the total distinct vehicles per day, then from that, what was the total vehicles per year that ran at the peak hours. The maximum number of vehicles that ran on any day that had the most vehicles out at the same time, and what time was that. Really good language though

Comment: @BobbyKuhn  To get distinct vehicles over a period of time try  Busses = cast(count(Distinct bus) as float)/count(Distinct service_date)

Comment: this is what I have changed. this returns every day and the peak for that day, but the min out and max out are the max for the filter applied. Which is what I asked for, but how would I make this the max out for each day. As I would like to just make this a view and see the peaks per day.--Select service_date ,MinOut ,MaxOut,Busses = cast(count(Distinct bus) as float)/count(Distinct service_date)
  Join cteBase B on (OutTime between MinOut and MaxOut)
 Group By service_date,MinOut,MaxOut
 order by service_date

Comment: @BobbyKuhn Sorry, a little unclear. Do you want peak per service day or peak per day of week

Comment: If it were peak per service day that would be best. I just think if I had this as a view, I could respond to customers challengers by showing them one day and testing the results on a limited basis.

Comment: @BobbyKuhn Added another answer

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT phour AS peak_hour,
       bus_cnt AS peak_count
  FROM
     (
       SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY bus_cnt DESC ,partition by bus_cnt ) AS rnk

         FROM 
            (
               SELECT cast( DATEPART( hour, leave_yard ) as varchar )+ ':00:00' AS phour,
                      COUNT( bus ) AS bus_cnt 
                 FROM fixedrouterecords
                GROUP BY cast( DATEPART( hour, leave_yard )
             )y
      )z
WHERE z.rnk = 1;`

Comment: the error is Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'by'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'y'.